# IF function with multiple conditions

Tags: excel, if-statement

I've been trying to figure this out for the past two hours. I need to create a nested IF statement based on this info. Here's the question:

Incentive: A dollar amount which is based on a percentage discount of the house price as indicated on the Data section of the spreadsheet. It's given only to selected customers complying with any of these conditions:

- The house located in New Jersey, zone 2 and is a multiple dwelling.
- The house located in California, zone1.
- The house located in Florida, single unit.

And here's an image of the Excel provided:

[image: image here]

This is what I currently have:

```
=IF(OR((B10="New Jersey", C10="2", D10="Multiple"), (B10="California", C10="1")), ($B$4*E10), "No"
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: is your column C text or numbers? Remove the center alignment, if it aligns to right, it's a number and you should use C10=2 instead of C10="2"

Comment: your New Jersey / 2 / Multiple should be in a AND structure `IF(OR(AND(NJ,2,Multiple),AND(CA,1)...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(OR(AND(B10="New Jersey", --N(C10)=2, D10="Multiple"), AND(B10="California", --N(C10)="1"),AND(B10="Florida", D10="Single")), ($B$4*E10), "No")
```

You need to:

- include a `AND`structure
- get the right datatype for your C column (is it number, or is it text)

Comment: I believe it's text; it doesn't automatically right-align if I remove the center alignment.

Comment: With =IF(OR(AND(B10="New Jersey", -N(C10)=2, D10="Multiple"), AND(B10="California", --N(C10)=1),AND(B10="Florida", D10="Single")), ($B$4*E10), "No"), all of the results are generating correctly aside from New Jersey's. All of New Jersey's are coming as "No," when there should be three that give the incentive number.

Comment: Whoops, I accidentally wrote -N instead of --N. Everything is working well now; thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

As previously stated, the error lies in your logic structure. Try the below formula:

```
=IFERROR(IF(OR(AND($B10="New Jersey",TEXT($C10,"#")=2,$D10="Multiple"),AND($B10="California",TEXT($C10,"#")=1),AND($B10="Florida",$D10="Single")),$B$4*$E10,"No"),"Error!")
```

We start with the `OR` function inside the `IF` function because we want to check if *any* of the following conditions are true. We follow that with three separate `AND` functions, each one testing your parameters. Should one of these `AND` functions return true for each statement within it, you will get `$B$4*$E10` as your value; otherwise, we return **No**. I chose to wrap this all up in an `IFERROR` so that you can capture any potential errors (should they occur).

Also, I handled for the potential "number-formatted-as-text" issue by converting it to a number within the calculation.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Much appreciated!